# Atribute Checking inside Class Python

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I would like to know what's the best practice to validate an input in a `__init__` in Python.

I generally validate it before summoning the object, but I think it's not the best choice. As far as I know, a class should be responsible for dealing with it's attributes and recognize if they're good to be used.

Example:

Let's create a class called Time that it has "hour", "minute" and "second" as parameters (all int) and it's needed to instantly convert them to usual representation.
Constructor receives attributes: 10h - 75min - 70sec.
Should be converted during constructor(?): 11h - 16min - 10 sec.

What's the Pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Depends on how you want the class to be used. Do you need to keep the original values ? One possible solution is to use properties that will perform the conversion on the fly.

Comment: Could you provide some code example? The original values aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to validate an attribute you should define a property method in which you can do so. Consider this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self._age = age

    @property
    def _age(self):
        return self._age

    @_age.setter
    def _age(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Age can not be less than zero!')
        self._age = value


p = Person(-5)
```

Running this snippet results into an ValueError. This way you can whether raise an exception (like it's done in the snippet) or change the given value to something valid. This decision is up to you.